# Acquiring children from an object separately with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to retrieve each child in the database structure below, separately? For instance, I'd like to retrieve a specific user ID (like `0e2034ce-bdb0-4623-9f9e-84e302a78354`), and the name, latitude and longitude belonging to that ID, all separately. Listed below is my current attempt, together with the database structure and how information is added.

```
// Current attempt
userData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child()
            String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Name").getValue();
            String latitude = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Lat").getValue();
            String longitude = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Lng").getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

// The database structure
Users
    0e2034ce-bdb0-4623-9f9e-84e302a78354
        Name:
        Lat: 
        Lng:
    26d14b76-8341-4167-a670-905e5a58f5db
        Name:
        Lat: 
        Lng:  

// How data is added to the database
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userData = mRootRef.child("Users");

userData = mRootRef.child("Users").child(thisUser.getUserID()); //getUserID() returns a random string like 0e2034ce-bdb0-4623-9f9e-84e302a78354
userData.setValue("");
userData.child("Name").setValue(mName);
userData.child("Lat").setValue(mLatitude);
userData.child("Lng").setValue(mLongitude);
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code to get the data as needed.

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    String mName= (String) map.get("Name");
    String mLatitude= (String) map.get("Lat");
    String mLongitude= (String) map.get("Lng");
    arrayList.add(mName+ ", " + mLatitude + ", " + mLongitude);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list, arrayList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The listener is now indeed "activated" when data is added, however the values of mName, mLatitude, mLongitude are all set to null. Also, how should the UserID be retrieved?

Comment: First of all, you need to remove this line: `userData.setValue("");` beacause in this way, you are setting `child(thisUser.getUserID()` in the reference to null. The best practice to get the `userId` is like this: `String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();` or if you are using in your app Google authentication you can use: `String userId = googleSignInAccount.getId();` Hope it helps!